# Open graph tags not rendered in facebook like

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have used facebook open graph tags for facebook like but they are not rendered.The default meta title and description is showing on while posting on facebook. Here is demo url http://www.mypartyaid.com/event/photodetail/1913-lust-after-work-wednesdays-at-katra-nyc-4393214

When i debug it using debugger its giving the error **"You have tags ouside of your . This is either because your was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree, or you accidentally put your Open Graph tags in the wrong place. Either way you need to fix it before the tags are usable."**

while the og tags are in head.

Comment: Your html is invalid. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mypartyaid.com%2Fevent%2Fphotodetail%2F1913-lust-after-work-wednesdays-at-katra-nyc-4393214&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem seems to be here:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

**If you change it to:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

It should work fine.